# RSA How many value for d

Tags: rsa

How many value can have a private key with this format? p,q,d = (19, 41, d) where  1< d <18x40?

I want know how to calculate that.

Comment: This seems like a homework question. What have you tried? Note that we only give hints for homework questions, and then only after some effort can be shown from your part solving it.

Comment: I think the question has also already been asked.
[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16310871/how-to-find-d-given-p-q-and-e-in-rsa)

Comment: It is a type of homework, in fact I made a few attempts, I thought of calculating how many possible values ​​it could take and with respect to the Euler function of the module. But even so I don't know how to approach d not having a precise value for e. I guess there is an easy formula or at least a quick way to calculate it but also by looking on the internet I am not finding anything. I guess I searched badly.

Comment: First you need to define when you accept a $d$ as valid. If the problem statement is not clear enough about that, first re-state it, if the form for answering allows. The simplest possible reading is: when exists $e$ with $e\,d\equiv1\pmod{\varphi(p\,q)}$. The answer is then easy, stick to that if there is no more context and your goal is to get rid of an assignment. But perhaps the criteria is something else, more functional? For example, an RSA key pair where encryption and decryption both are identity might be rejected, and that could be why the question rejects $d=1$.

Comment: The other obvious question is "is this for a specific (and not specified) allowable value of $e$", or "is this the total number of possible values of $d$, over all possible values of $e$"?  Note that, in the first case, there is a unique answer, independent of $e$ (if we assume $e=1$ and $e=361$ are "not allowed")